# Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `router` was not specified in `RouterContext`

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I've been working several days to get the static site boilerplate up and running using a mix of react, react-router and webpack. Unfortunately I've been having great difficulty tracking down the source of a bug. To generate the static pages I'm running `webpack --progress --colors --display-error-details --bail`, which results in the following output (the react warnings presumably being emitted at time of rendering):

```
90% optimize assetsWarning: Failed propType: Required prop `router` was not specified in `RouterContext`.
    Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `location` was not specified in `RouterContext`.
    Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `routes` was not specified in `RouterContext`.
    Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `params` was not specified in `RouterContext`.
    Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `components` was not specified in `RouterContext`.
    Warning: [react-router] `<RouterContext>` expects a `router` rather than a `history`
    Warning: [react-router] `<RouterContext>` expects a `router` rather than a `history`
    Warning: [react-router] `<RouterContext>` expects a `router` rather than a `history`
    Warning: [react-router] `<RouterContext>` expects a `router` rather than a `history`
    Warning: [react-router] `<RouterContext>` expects a `router` rather than a `history`
    Warning: [react-router] `<RouterContext>` expects a `router` rather than a `history`
    Hash: 6666e7e25ed1cee9bca3
    Version: webpack 1.13.0
    Time: 2189ms
                Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    production.min.js    2.33 MB       0  [emitted]  router
          sitemap.xml  549 bytes          [emitted]  
        + 245 hidden modules

    ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'listenBeforeLeavingRoute' of undefined
        at getChildContext (eval at <anonymous> (router:471:2), <anonymous>:80:35)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._processChildContext (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:413:53)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performInitialMount (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:297:127)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:222:21)
        at wrapper [as mountComponent] (eval at <anonymous> (router:789:2), <anonymous>:66:21)
        at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:795:2), <anonymous>:39:35)
        at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren (eval at <anonymous> (router:1119:2), <anonymous>:203:44)
        at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup (eval at <anonymous> (router:957:2), <anonymous>:593:32)
        at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:957:2), <anonymous>:478:29)
        at ReactDOMComponent.wrapper [as mountComponent] (eval at <anonymous> (router:789:2), <anonymous>:66:21)

    ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'listenBeforeLeavingRoute' of undefined
        at getChildContext (eval at <anonymous> (router:471:2), <anonymous>:80:35)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._processChildContext (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:413:53)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performInitialMount (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:297:127)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:222:21)
        at wrapper [as mountComponent] (eval at <anonymous> (router:789:2), <anonymous>:66:21)
        at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:795:2), <anonymous>:39:35)
        at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren (eval at <anonymous> (router:1119:2), <anonymous>:203:44)
        at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup (eval at <anonymous> (router:957:2), <anonymous>:593:32)
        at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:957:2), <anonymous>:478:29)
        at ReactDOMComponent.wrapper [as mountComponent] (eval at <anonymous> (router:789:2), <anonymous>:66:21)

    ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'listenBeforeLeavingRoute' of undefined
        at getChildContext (eval at <anonymous> (router:471:2), <anonymous>:80:35)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._processChildContext (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:413:53)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performInitialMount (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:297:127)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:222:21)
        at wrapper [as mountComponent] (eval at <anonymous> (router:789:2), <anonymous>:66:21)
        at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:795:2), <anonymous>:39:35)
        at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren (eval at <anonymous> (router:1119:2), <anonymous>:203:44)
        at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup (eval at <anonymous> (router:957:2), <anonymous>:593:32)
        at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:957:2), <anonymous>:478:29)
        at ReactDOMComponent.wrapper [as mountComponent] (eval at <anonymous> (router:789:2), <anonymous>:66:21)

    ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'listenBeforeLeavingRoute' of undefined
        at getChildContext (eval at <anonymous> (router:471:2), <anonymous>:80:35)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._processChildContext (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:413:53)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performInitialMount (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:297:127)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:222:21)
        at wrapper [as mountComponent] (eval at <anonymous> (router:789:2), <anonymous>:66:21)
        at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:795:2), <anonymous>:39:35)
        at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren (eval at <anonymous> (router:1119:2), <anonymous>:203:44)
        at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup (eval at <anonymous> (router:957:2), <anonymous>:593:32)
        at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:957:2), <anonymous>:478:29)
        at ReactDOMComponent.wrapper [as mountComponent] (eval at <anonymous> (router:789:2), <anonymous>:66:21)

    ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'listenBeforeLeavingRoute' of undefined
        at getChildContext (eval at <anonymous> (router:471:2), <anonymous>:80:35)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._processChildContext (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:413:53)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performInitialMount (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:297:127)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:222:21)
        at wrapper [as mountComponent] (eval at <anonymous> (router:789:2), <anonymous>:66:21)
        at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:795:2), <anonymous>:39:35)
        at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren (eval at <anonymous> (router:1119:2), <anonymous>:203:44)
        at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup (eval at <anonymous> (router:957:2), <anonymous>:593:32)
        at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:957:2), <anonymous>:478:29)
        at ReactDOMComponent.wrapper [as mountComponent] (eval at <anonymous> (router:789:2), <anonymous>:66:21)

    ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'listenBeforeLeavingRoute' of undefined
        at getChildContext (eval at <anonymous> (router:471:2), <anonymous>:80:35)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._processChildContext (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:413:53)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performInitialMount (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:297:127)
        at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:1143:2), <anonymous>:222:21)
        at wrapper [as mountComponent] (eval at <anonymous> (router:789:2), <anonymous>:66:21)
        at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:795:2), <anonymous>:39:35)
        at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren (eval at <anonymous> (router:1119:2), <anonymous>:203:44)
        at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup (eval at <anonymous> (router:957:2), <anonymous>:593:32)
        at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent (eval at <anonymous> (router:957:2), <anonymous>:478:29)
        at ReactDOMComponent.wrapper [as mountComponent] (eval at <anonymous> (router:789:2), <anonymous>:66:21)
```

My webpack.config.babel.js

```
import path from 'path'
import webpack from 'webpack'
import SiteMapPlugin from 'sitemap-webpack-plugin'
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin'
import StaticSiteGeneratorWebpackPlugin from 'static-site-generator-webpack-plugin'

const locals = {}

const paths = [
  '/',
  '/Simon',
  '/Pomodoro',
  '/TicTacToe',
  '/Calculator',
  '/404.html',
]

export default {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',

  entry: {
    router: "./src/router" 
  },

  output: {
    path: './dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    filename: 'production.min.js'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: [
            'babel-preset-es2016',
            'babel-preset-react',
            'babel-preset-stage-0'
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!resolve-url-loader!sass-loader')
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new StaticSiteGeneratorWebpackPlugin("router", paths, locals),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("production.min.css", {allChunks: true}),
    new SiteMapPlugin("http://Travmatth.github.io/react-static-site", paths),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.es6']
  }
}
```

Router.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import Index from './Index'
import routes from './routes'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import {Router, RouterContext, match, browserHistory, createMemoryHistory} from 'react-router'

const createElement = (Component, props) => {
  return <Component {...props} />
}

if (typeof document !== "undefined") {
  ReactDOM.render((
    <Router createElement={createElement} history={browserHistory}>
      {routes}
    </Router>), 
    document.getElementById('app'))
}

export default ({assets, path}, callback) => {
  const location = createMemoryHistory().createLocation(path)

  match({routes, location}, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (err) {
      throw new Error(err)
    }

    const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
      <Index assets={assets}>
        <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
      </Index>
    )

    callback(null, `<!DOCTYPE html>${html}`)
  })
}
```

Routes.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import Index from './Index'
import Simon from './Components/Simon'
import Landing from './Components/Landing'
import Pomodoro from './Components/Pomodoro'
import NotFound from './Components/NotFound'
import TicTacToe from './Components/TicTacToe'
import Calculator from './Components/Calculator'
import {IndexRoute, Route, Router} from 'react-router'

const routes = (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" components={Index}>
      <IndexRoute components={Landing}/>
      <Route path="/Simon" components={Simon}/>
      <Route path="/Pomodoro" components={Pomodoro}/>
      <Route path="/TicTacToe" components={TicTacToe}/>
      <Route path="/Calculator " components={Calculator}/>
      <Route path="*" components={NotFound}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
)

export {routes};
```

Index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router'
import HTMLDocument from 'react-html-document'

export default class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const metatags = [
      {
        name: 'viewport',
        content: 'maximum-scale=1,' + 
                 'initial-scale=1,' +
                 'width=device-width'
      },
      {
        name: 'content-type',
        content: 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
      }
    ]

    const scripts = [ '/production.min.js' ]
    const stylesheets = ["/production.min.css"]

    return (
      <HTMLDocument title="A sensible react static site" 
                    stylesheets={stylesheets}
                    metatags={metatags}
                    scripts={scripts}>
        <div id="app">
          {this.props.children}
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/Simon">Simon</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/Pomodoro">Pomodoro</Link></li> 
            <li><Link to="/TicTacToe">TicTacToe</Link></li> 
            <li><Link to="/Calculator">Calculator</Link></li> 
          </ul>
        </div>
      </HTMLDocument>
    )
  }
}
```

All other related files and directory structure can be found here: [github](https://github.com/Travmatth/react-static-site). I'm hoping someone has seen similar problems or has suggestions as to find out more about what is malfunctioning.

Comment: Have you seen this https://github.com/spartansystems/react-webpack-static-example?